# C++ - Visual Studio's compiler set up in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, codeblocks

Honestly I like Code::Blocks (v13.12) much more than Visual Studio because it doesn't eat up my RAM. I was wondering: I recently installed Visual Studio 2012 Professional, and attempted to set the compiler up to work with Code::Blocks, but upon viewing the files included, I was missing a few critical C++ headers and, in addition, Microsoft's resource compiler, therefore I could not successfully get it working with Code::Blocks. There were no errors when I installed Visual Studio, so why would I be missing headers and their resource compiler? Are those not included in the professional version? Do I seriously need to get a copy of ultimate?

Comment: That's so strange... Even though VS 2013 eats 3 times more memory (200 MBytes vs 80 MBytes on my machine) it is 10 times better IDE, and only compiler sucks. But anyway, what headers are you missing? Did you tried to search over `$(VC_IncludePath)` and
`$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)`? Didn't you think about using GCC instead?

Comment: I read an article that said GCC produces non-standard PE code, which I believe. That's why I want to compile with MS's compiler.